# In Mocha test scripts the try/catch block is swallowing errors

Tags: javascript, try-catch, mocha.js

I am facing an issue with try/catch in Mocha script. Eventhough some of the tests are failing but Mocha is displaying as "All are passed". Below is my test script file help me in fixing this issue. In this code, I am posting a input string from an array to an URL and expecting XML response. I am using Xml2js module to parse Xml response to JSON string and comparing XML child elements with expect

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var request = require('supertest');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var PrettyError = require('pretty-error');
var pe = new PrettyError();


var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs');
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
var build = require('./config').Build;

var build_url = build.Environment[build.Type].HostUrl;

    var inputArray1 = [];

    describe('Verifying Incoming post output response', function() {
     var index = 0;
     validateFields(index);

     function validateFields(index) {
      var input = inputArray1[index];

      var actualInputArray = input.split(",");

      describe(actualInputArray[0], function() {
       it(actualInputArray[1], function(done) {
        request(build_url).post('/lead')
         .send(actualInputArray[2])
         .end(function(err, res) {
          var resxml = res.text;
          console.log("resxml", resxml);
          parser.parseString(resxml, function(err, result) {
           try {
            expect(result['Header']['RESULT']).to.deep.equal([actualInputArray[3]]);
            expect(result['Header']['STATUS_CODE']).to.deep.equal([actualInputArray[4]]);
            expect(result['Header']['MESSAGE']).to.deep.equal( [actualInputArray[5]]); 

           } catch (err) {
            console.log(pe.render(err.message));

           }
           index = index + 1;
           if (index < inputArray1.length) {
            validateFields(index);
           }

           done();
          });
         });
       }).timeout(5000);
      });
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you catch the error the done() method is still called and resolve the promise, so all your tests will pass anyway.

Try to add `done(new Error("Your error message"));` to the catch and let fail the test in case of error.

Comment: I have removed done() after the else block and placed  **done(new Error(pe.render(err.message))); **  in catch block. Now mocha is displaying Total pass and fail count correctly. **But I am getting Time out error now**

Comment: if you  call the done() in the catch, in case of success the promise will never be resolved and you will end up with a timeout.